# Filtering of nodes basing on the sibling nodes

Tags: mapping, sap-pi

Below is the input XML and I need to pass the text of node "`desc`" to target node only when "`lang`" node is EN if there is no EN present in the GP nodes then whatever language comes first it needs to be passed to target node (see below expected output).

I tried "equal string" and "if" functions to achieve this but failing to achieve, all the false are assigned to non EN and this creates a mess.

I achieved this using groovy scripting but How can I achieve this in Graphical Mapping?

Input XML:

```xml
<Root>
  <GP1>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>EN</Lang>
      <desc>hello</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>DE</Lang>
      <desc>gutentag</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>EN</Lang>
      <desc>Good morning</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>EN</Lang>
      <desc>Hellothere</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>DE</Lang>
      <desc>Guten Morg</desc>
    </Parent>
  </GP1>
  <GP2>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>DE</Lang>
      <desc>gutentag</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>HND</Lang>
      <desc>Namaskar</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>SPN</Lang>
      <desc>HOLA</desc>
    </Parent>
  </GP2>
</Root>
```

The Output should be like this

```xml
<Root>
  <GP1>
    <Parent>
      <Title>Hello</Title>
      <Title>GoodMorning</Title>
      <Title>Hellothere</Title>
    </Parent>
  </GP1>
  <GP2>
    <Parent>
      <Title>GutenTag</Title>
    </Parent>
  </GP2>
</Root>
```